# Problem in set up environment in VScode for React Native using Expo Cli

Tags: node.js, react-native, visual-studio-code, installation, expo

I am a newbie in React Native and I am trying to set up the environment for it in VScode using Expo Cli. Even though I follow all the steps in Youtube, I still can't make it. I have installed Node.js and extension of React Native. I have opened the port for the Metro Bundler and Web but I don't know why I can't open them.
Here are pictures of my screen. This is my first post, so I'm not allowed to post pictures but links. Sorry for the inconvenience.

[1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpnV.png)

[2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iWY0.png)

I have no clue how to fix it so I try to search for the problem, but nothing has improved.